# If clause with dropbox

Tags: javascript, grails

Hello I have the following checkbox

```
       <div class="checkbox">
            <label for="sendEmail">
                <g:checkBox name="sendEmail" checked="${sendEmail == 'on'}"
                onchange="swapFieldsets(this, '#sa-email', '#sa-password')" />
                <g:message code="onBoard.noAccessEmail" default="Send Access Email" />
            </label>
        </div>
```

and if it is on/off it does this :

```
    <fieldset id="sa-email" ${raw(sendEmail == "on" ? "" : "class='hidden' disabled")}>

        <g:render template="businessEmailFields" bean="${pEmail}" />
    </fieldset>
  <fieldset id="sa-password" ${raw(sendEmail != "on" ? "" : "class='hidden' disabled")}>

     <g:render template="homeEmailFields" bean="${pEmail}" />
    </fieldset>
```

Now I want to remove the checkbox by replacing it with this 
and keep the same logic

```
  <g:select name="book.category" from="${['Choice1', 'Choice2']}"
               />
```

and if we select from the menu Choice1 to render

```
<g:render template="homeEmailFields" bean="${pEmail}"/>
```

and if we choose Choice2 to render the other page

To sum up I want to : I just want to remove the checkbox and replace it with dropdown menu which has options 'Choice1' and 'Choice2'.And you can see with the hitbox if it is on we should render a page ,now I don't want to chech if it is on I want to check if we have selected from the dropdown menu 'Choice1'

Comment: Can you please add a clear problem statement? At the moment, I cannot understand what you're asking.

Comment: Yes sure,I just want to remove the checkbox and replace it with dropdown menu which has options 'Choice1' and 'Choice2'.And you can see with the hitbox if it is on we should render a page ,now I don't want to chech if it is on I want to check if we have selected from the dropdown menu 'Choice1'

Comment: I would say this is rather a strange way of doing things, usually you would capture the change either via onChange or jquery on change method then using ajax load in the template within div. You see to be checking value of checkbox in gsp (grails) rather than javascript.

Comment: how can it happen on the dropbox with onChange?

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned on my comments typically you have a [select box](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-queuekit-plugin/blob/master/grails-app/views/queueKit/_search.gsp#L7-L9)

```
<g:select class="form-control small" name="adminButtons" from="${adminButtons}"
noSelection="${['':"${g.message(code:'queuekit.chooseAdminAction.label')}"]}"
  valueMessagePrefix="queuekit.adminButton"/>
```

Which then gets called [through jquery](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-queuekit-plugin/blob/master/grails-app/views/queueKit/_search.gsp#L86-L92) but you would then [change that to](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-queuekit-plugin/blob/master/grails-app/views/queueKit/main.gsp#L220-L227)

```
$('#adminButtons').on('change', function() {
        var value = $('#adminButtons').val();
        if (value!='') {
            var params=$.param({changeType:value});         
            var url='${createLink(controller:'queueKit',action:'changeConfig')}?'+params
            $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            //data: $('#search').serialize(),
            success: function(data){
                 //Where #results id the DIV id that the template is loaded 
                 //into which would be your template you are loading
                $('#results').html(data);
            }
        });
        }
    });
```

But then that is not attempting to lookup the actual value via the gsp to alter gsp - your gsp would then be loaded via the ajax call to your controller loading up a template that would be your template...

So a little different to how you are doing things but typically how javascript interaction is done